When replacing a floor, how do I ensure it doesn't creak?
I have hardwood from the 50s on most of the main level of my house.  It hasn't been well taken care of (it's had carpet stapled into it at more than one point and is generally pretty badly worn and warped).
I know that restoring it is an option, but the gaps between planks and the seasonal expansion/contraction have convinced me that I don't actually want hardwood.  I want to replace it - is ripping it up and putting down new subfloor and underlayment for a LVP or similar solution the best option?  My highest priorities are avoiding creaking (current planks creak a LOT) and not having the project take 34 years.
I'll probably be doing most of the work myself.
Can I treat the hardwood as a subfloor and build on top with new underlayment and LVP, or will the creaks not go away?  Additionally, in places where the floor is warped, is self-leveling cement an option or do I really need to be ripping down to subfloor?

Taking it down to the subfloor is your best option, if silent floors are your main priority. You now have only one variable to solve for any creaks.
Once you've done that, walk across your subfloor and listen for any creaking. Apply additional screws into the joists in the area of the creaks. You may also need to go underneath and shim between the joist and the subfloor to solve the creaking noise.
Once you are satisfied with the performance, find your low spots and apply your self leveling compound, feathering the edges. Your level requirements are relative to the existing floor.
Apply your underlayment (I like to apply a 1/2" plywood for the additional stiffness) and screw down, ideally through the joists. Consider also applying polyurethane construction adhesive in addition to the screws to the underside of the underlayment.
Install your flooring of choice.

Well, you can still have creaking from the subfloor-joist connections...may need to even replace subfloor.  And you never know if something may creak after the additional weight of flooring is added.
